# ExoPlayer - disabling autoplay in ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: android

Subj.
This seems to be the basic functionality yet I am failing to find any info.
I tried to pause the player in onPositionDiscontinuity (if the reason of discontinuity is DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION), but the player still plays like 1-2 seconds of the next source.